# Not able to set Proxy setting for api.ai call from python

Tags: python, anaconda, http-proxy, dialogflow-es

I am making a request to my api.ai chatbot after following the instructions given on their official github website [here](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-python-client/blob/master/examples/send_text_example.py). The following is the code for which I am getting an error, to which the solution is supposedly to call the function with proxy settings. I however do not know a way to do so.`

```
ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
request = ai.text_request()
request.set_proxy('proxy1.company.com:8080','http')
question = input()
request.query = question
response = request.getresponse()`
```

I get the following error on the last line.

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Please suggest how I use the proxy settings.
I am using Anaconda on Windows to run the script.

Comment: is there any password for your proxy?

Comment: It does. But the problem here is that the api.ai python module doesn not provide any way of invoking using proxy settings.

Comment: can you show what the following gives: `help(request.set_proxy)` and `dir(request.set_proxy)` and `dir(request)`

Comment: The first two statements give `RuntimeError: Working outside of request context`. The third returns an empty list. What does this suggest?

Comment: You need to do it this way: `ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN);
request = ai.text_request(); print help(request.set_proxy); print dir(request.set_proxy); print dir(request)`

Comment: The first two statements complain that no attribute `set_proxy` exists. The third statement returns the following.
`['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__',`

Comment: `'_beforegetresponce', '_client_access_token', '_connect', '_connection', '_connection_class', '_contexts', '_entities', '_lang', '_prepage_begin_request_data', '_prepage_end_request_data', '_prepare_entities', '_prepare_headers', '_prepare_proxy', '_prepare_request', '_query', '_resetContexts', '_session_id', '_time_zone', 'base_url', 'client_access_token', 'contexts', 'entities', 'getresponse', 'lang', 'path', 'proxy_enabled', 'query', 'query_parameters', 'resetContexts', 'send', 'session_id', 'time_zone', 'version']`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might work:

First you need to set your proxy from `cmd`:

```
$ set https_proxy=http://yourusername:yourpassword@proxy1.wipro.com:8080
```

Then remove the `request.set_proxy()` line from your code. i.e.,

```
ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
request = ai.text_request()
question = input()
request.query = question
response = request.getresponse()
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code I use to make get requests, if they fail then I make a new request behind a proxy. I have some Class specified here but you can drop it.

```
class AllNames:
""" This class stores all names of directory, sites..."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
        self.munich_code = "id=2867714"
        self.appid = "&appid=xxxxxx"
        self.proxies = {"http": "http://user:pw@proxy.muc:8080", "https": "http://user:pw@proxy.muc:8080"}

    def get_munich_weather_data():
    """
    This module gets JSON formatted Weather data for Munich from Open Weather Map ORG and returns a Python
    representation of the data.

    :return: Python dictionnary object with weather data for Munich.
    """
        all_names = AllNames()
        complete_url = all_names.url + all_names.munich_code + all_names.appid
        try:
            req = requests.get(complete_url)
        except ConnectionError:
            req = requests.get(complete_url, proxies=all_names.proxies)
        texts = req.text
        return [ast.literal_eval(texts)]
```